# C#: What takes up more memory? A string or bytearray?

Tags: c#, .net, string, arrays

C#: What takes up more memory? A string or bytes?

Let's say I have a line that reads "My Text", in which form would that line use up more memory, as a byte or a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The byte array. This will store your text as ASCII (1 byte per character) characters, whereas a .NET string uses Unicode which are larger. However remember that .NET strings are probably more useful and in a large application the difference probably won't make a huge difference.

(note also that if you just use ASCII characters in your .NET string then the characters will still only be 1 byte each)

Comment: Awesome first answer, dude! +1

Comment: Very VERY informative answer. I am very thankful for your informative response. I can't stress this enough but THANK YOU!

Comment: If you store it as a byte array, you will generally be able to store ASCII only - if you need extended UTF8 characters at all, use a string and take the memory hit, if saving a few bytes is that important.

Comment: I don't know if this answer is entirely correct. The fact that Sytem.Char uses UTF-16 encoding does not mean that the char WILL occupy more than one byte, right? Specifically "My Text", wouldn't.

Comment: Sorry about my last comment. I didn't see the edit about ASCII.

Comment: Also remember, that an empty string requires more memory than an empty byte[]

Comment: ....Huh? The byte array takes up more memory because .NET strings are larger?

Am I the only one struggling to understand this post?

Comment: This is an old answer made when I was quite a bit younger and less knowledgeable. May I draw your attention towards the more informative, useful and higher rated answer below.

Answer (score 14):

It depends on the character encoding of the byte array. You can convert any string into an array of bytes, but you have to choose the encoding; there is no single standard or correct encoding. What used to be called ASCII is no use outside of the English speaking world.

In most encodings, "My Text" would be 7 bytes long. But throw in some European accented characters, or Japanese characters, and those (if they can be represented at all) may be more than one or two bytes each. In some encodings, with some text strings, the byte-array representation may be larger than the internal Unicode representation used by `System.String`.

Comment: IMO, a better answer than the accepted one, since it stresses the importance of the encoding choice.

Comment: There's no justice in the world, I tells ya.

Answer (score 3):

> What takes up more memory?

So you are asking about the size of the **in-memory representation**. .net uses **UTF-16** for strings, which means your example will be represented by 14 bytes, as can be seen in this hex dump (UTF-16LE):

```
4d 00 79 00 20 00 54 00  65 00 78 00 74 00
```

**The size of the byte array will depend on the encoding** that you use to represent the text. If you use **UTF-16**, like this

```
Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(string)
```

you obviously get the same 14 bytes. If you use **UTF-8** instead:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string)
```

you get an array of 7 bytes:

```
4d 79 20 54 65 78 74
```

This is the same size (and the same representation) as **ASCII**, because your example only uses characters that are available in the ASCII charset. All those characters are, per definition, the same in UTF-8.

Now if you use **non-ASCII characters** instead, say the Japanese "日", the UTF-8 encoding would need 3 bytes:

```
e6 97 a5
```

UTF-16 would need only 2 bytes:

```
e5 65
```

Trying to convert the Japanese character to ASCII would yield an exception or just use a "?" character, depending on how you configure the `Encoding`, because ASCII cannot represent anything but ASCII characters.

Another slightly different example, the European character "ä". 2 bytes in UTF-8:

```
c3 a4
```

Also 2 bytes in UTF-16:

```
e4 00
```

ASCII can't represent this character.

To sum up, **the memory consumed depends on the actual data in your strings and what encoding you use to represent it**.

All the above talks about the memory consumption for the **raw data** only, please note that in order to calculate the **total memory consumption** you'd also have to include **metadata** that is part of every array and string, like its **length**, and, in the case of .net strings, also a **null terminator** (2 additional bytes with the value '0'). The number of bytes for the metadata is constant and relatively small, so any difference between string and array there would only matter if you had tons of very small texts.

Answer (score 2):

Being Unicode doesn't mean that the string will take more than one byte per character, it just means it "could" take up more than one byte per character.

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: It depends on the type of unicode. UTF16 does take up more than one per character

Comment: Exactly, as I said... it "could". You've also mixed up "character" and "byte" in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Both are pretty close.  Only one real answer:

Profile it on your framework/architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The byte array would take less memory unless you had several copies of the string, in which case the string would take up less memory thanks to the string table.

But the *real* questions is, does it really matter? There are a lot of benefits you get to using the string as a string, rather than storing it as an array of bytes.

I don't know the particulars, since your question was very narrow, but I smell premature optimization.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good blog post [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/jcrease/archive/2009/01/16/71678.aspx) that gives an equation for how much space a string takes up, as well as various interactions with StringBuilder & instance allocations