# Which is the efficient way to send the data from angular application to microservice via websocket (string or ArrayBuffer)?

Tags: c#, angular, websocket

We have an angular application which communicates to the microservice to get the data. Most of the communication happens via the Websocket since we need the communication to be async. Our request will mostly have a JSON serialized object of different types(the type is also passed as part of the request to enable deserialization on server side). WebSocket supports sending data as string, ArrayBuffer and blob.

The question is Which is efficient - string or ArrayBuffer ?

When I say efficient I would consider less data sent from server to client.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C#: What takes up more memory? A string or bytearray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/913036/c-what-takes-up-more-memory-a-string-or-bytearray)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do care about payload, `Arraybuffer` is definately smaller in size than `String`.

I suggest that you could do further to zip and pack your message by using protobuf, messagepack...